# Spring Security - Доступ запрещен

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Хочу реализовать в своем проекте возможность подписок и подписчиков, когда вызываю метод, который добавляет текущего юзера в подписчики автору, то вылетает ошибка.

User (Entity)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sweater_user")
public class User implements UserDetails{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank(message = "Username should not be empty")
    private String username;

    @NotBlank(message = "Password should not be empty")
    private String password;

    @Email(message = "Email is not correct")
    @NotBlank(message = "Email should not be empty")
    private String email;

    private String activationCode;

    private boolean active;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "sweater_user_role",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    private Collection<Role> roles;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Collection<Message> messages;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_subscriptions",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "channel_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "subscriber_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    private Set<User> subscribers = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_subscriptions",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "subscriber_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "channel_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    private Set<User> subscriptions = new HashSet<>();

    public User(String username, String password, String email, String activationCode, boolean active, Collection<Role> roles) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
        this.activationCode = activationCode;
        this.active = active;
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public User() {
    }

    public boolean isAdmin(){
        return roles.contains(new Role("ADMIN"));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return isActive();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return getRoles();
    }
```

Controller

```
@GetMapping("subscribe/{author}")
    public String subscribeOnAuthor(@AuthenticationPrincipal User currentUser,
                                    @PathVariable("author") Long id){
        User author = userRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("User not exists with id " + id));
        author.getSubscribers().add(currentUser);
        userRepository.save(author);
        return "redirect:/main/" + author.getUsername();
    }
```

Ошибка:

```
Forbidden
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Доступ запрещен
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:73)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.attemptAuthorization(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:239)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:58)
```

Answer (score 0):

Не вижу метода isActive

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return isActive();
}
```

У тебя есть переменна active, попробуй возвращать её в isEnabled

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return active;
}
```

Comment: Так разницы никакой нет, а не видишь, потому что я не стал все геттеры и сеттеры вставлять, и ошибка именно при добавлении к юзеру в подписки или в подписчики, другие поля сохраняются в базе без проблем

Comment: А аутентификацию как проводишь? Есть провайдеры либо фильтры?